# Change font-size of label and input element's while hovering - HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css, input, hover, label

```
HTML:
<fieldset>
  <legend> XXX </legend>
  <label for="photo"> Photo </label>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
  <br>
  <label for="imagePreview"> Preview: </label>
  <img id="preview">
</fieldset>

CSS:
// 1. In this order, only input:hover works.
  label:hover { font-size: 25px;}
  input:hover { font-size: 20px;}

// 2. In this order, only label:hover works.
  input:hover { font-size: 20px;}
  label:hover { font-size: 25px;}
```

I was asked to do both should resize their font-size.

eg: Hovering on label, should change its font-size.
    Hovering on input, should change its font-size as well.

Why not both changing the font-size?
How can I achieve it?

Comment: What you need actually?

Comment: All the input elements  and labels should change its size while hovering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
fieldset { font-size: 20px;}
label:hover , input:hover { font-size: 25px;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> XXX </legend>
  <label for="photo"> Photo </label>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
  <br>
  <label for="imagePreview"> Preview: </label>
  <img id="preview">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like this

```css
fieldset { font-size: 20px;}
fieldset:hover label,fieldset:hover input { font-size: 25px;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend> XXX </legend>
  <label for="photo"> Photo </label>
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
  <br>
  <label for="imagePreview"> Preview: </label>
  <img id="preview">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Not fieldset hover, all <input>'s and <label>'s .

Comment: sorry! what you mean actually?

Comment: Hey. No need to be sorry. I found both of your answers are useful to me. Anyway thanks for the effort you took.